# CoffeeScript: what does the keyword 'super' do in this context?

Tags: class, coffeescript

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->

  move: (meters) ->
    alert @name + " moved #{meters}m."

class Snake extends Animal
   move: ->
    alert "Slithering..."
    super 5
```

So I was going through the CoffeeScript docs and ran into the above illustration of class extension. Can someone explain to me exactly what is happening when the line `super 5` is executed? I vaguely understand it is calling the super class's definition of `move` with the argument, 5, but what would the output look like if one called `mySnake.move` assuming my snake's name is `Robert`?

Comment: You can [run it yourself](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Animal%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40name)%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20move%3A%20(meters)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%40name%20%2B%20%22%20moved%20%23%7Bmeters%7Dm.%22%0A%0Aclass%20Snake%20extends%20Animal%0A%20%20move%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%22Slithering...%22%0A%20%20%20%20super%205%0A%0Asnake%20%3D%20new%20Snake('Robert')%0Asnake.move()) to see it's output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` will call the `move` method on the base class. Specifically, it will call the `Animal`  `move` method and pass in `5` as the `meters` parameter.

If you run the example on the CoffeeScript page, you should see an alert with "Sammy the Python moved 5m."

`super` is useful when your subclass has its own logic to run in addition to the base class implementation. You can place `super` right at the beginning of the method, or after additional code runs. Order might matter depending on the logic that's in place.

Comment: but is the contents of the subclass definition prepended to the same alert statement, or are there two alerts, "Slithering..." and then "Robert moved 5m" or is it "Slihtering...Robert moved 5m"

Comment: There are two alerts.

Comment: @Thalatta there will be 2 separate alerts. "Slithering..." then "Sammy the Python moved 5m." You can place the `super` call before or after any work to do in the `Snake.move` method. If you place it in the beginning, "Slithering..." will be displayed after "Sammy the Python moved 5m."